# Why is my stored procedure very much slower than the same MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, optimization

My stored procedure is very slow compared to a normal query or a temporary table. How can I optimize my stored procedure?

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`datasll`@`...` PROCEDURE `product`()
  BEGIN
  EXPLAIN SELECT  
         cs.id,
         cs.fk_c,
         cs.so, 
         cs.pr,
         cs.date,
         cs.o_p,
         cs.sh_c,
         cs.x,
         LEFT(cs.x,2),
         cs.doc,
         cs.fk_op,
         cc.id_c_c,
         cc.name,
         cc.descrip,
         left(cc.n_o,3) as bon,
         cc.fk_c_br,
         cc.de,
         cc.m_mat,
         cc.color, 
         cc.fk_c_s
  FROM
        data_pro.catas cs

  LEFT OUTER JOIN
        data_pro.c_co cc ON  data_pro.cs.fk_c_c = data_pro.cc._id_cc
  WHERE
        data_pro.cc.pap = 1
  AND   data_pro.cc.stati = 'b';
  END
```

When I use EXPLAIN this is the result:

[image]